# How do I change data after an $http request?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm making a web app in angular that is primarily driven with data from remote json objects. I want to load the page with sensible default data, then request the json objects and update the controllers with this new data.

Here's a snip from the service I made:

```
clickApp.factory('client', ['$http', function($http){

var logoUrl = "first";

var getConfig = function() {
    logoUrl = "second";

    $http({method: 'GET', url: base_url+'app-config.json'}).
        success(function(data, status) {
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available
            // console.log("data",data);

            console.log("logopre",logoUrl);
            logoUrl = "third";
            console.log("logopost",logoUrl);
        }).
    error(function(data, status) {
        console.log("error",status);
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
    });
};
getConfig();

return {
    logoUrl: logoUrl
}

}]);
```

I have a controller hooked up to this which just fills a p tag with logoUrl for the moment. With this code, the p tag is immediately updated to "second", the log value of "logopre" is "second" and the log value of "logopost" is "third", but the controller does *not* update the p tag to "third" like I expect.

I tried some fancy $scope.$watch statement in my controller as well, but that doesn't change the result.

**edit** I should note that I also tried $rootScope.$apply after the $http request but I could only get "$digest already in progress" errors.

**How can I properly update this value so it's reflected in my controller after the $http request?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (http://plnkr.co/edit/Fnrgo4?p=preview):

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, client) {
    $scope.client = client;
    $scope.$watch(function() {
        return client;
    }, function(client) {
        $scope.logoUrl = client.logoUrl;
    }, true);
});

app.factory('client', function($http, $log, $timeout) {
    var obj = {
        logoUrl: "first"
    };
    $log.info("logoinit", obj);
    var getConfig = function() {
            obj.logoUrl = "second";
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'app-config.json'
            }).
            success(function(data, status) {
                $log.info("logopre", obj);
                obj.logoUrl = "third";
                $log.info("logopost", obj);
            }).
            error(function(data, status) {
                $log.error("error", status);
            });
        };
    getConfig();

    return obj;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that works nicely. Can you explain how this works differently than my example? I tried some variant of $watch with no results.